# Summarize Leaflet controlLayers

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I cobbled together a code where I can print the features as a popup and wanted to make the objects on and off

```
var baseMaps = {
  "Wikimedia-Map": Wikimedia,
  "GrayCanvas-Map": Esri_WorldGrayCanvas,
  "Neighbourhood": Thunderforest_Neighbourhood,
  "WaterColor-Map": Stamen_Watercolor
};

var controlLayers = L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
   var geojsonLayer = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng] )
      .bindPopup('<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>'+
                    '<br/>Adresse: ' + markers[i].adresse +
                        '<br/>Ort: ' + markers[i].ort +
                            '<br/>Telefon: ' + markers[i].telefonnum +
                                '<br/>E-Mail: ' + markers[i].email +
                                    '<br/>Kategorie: ' + markers[i].kategorie + 
                                        '<br/>Art: ' + markers[i].art +
                                            '<br/>Bemerkung: ' + markers[i].bemerkung)


     .addTo(map);

    controlLayers.addOverlay(geojsonLayer, 'all');  
}
```

With this code, I found that this code outputs every single object as a clickable field (see screenshot)

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what code would be necessary to bring the objects together to a selectable group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add all markers to group layer and then add this group layer to map as overlay:

```
var markerLayer = L.layerGroup();

for ( var i=0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
   L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng] )
      .bindPopup('<a href="' + markers[i].url + '" target="_blank">' + markers[i].name + '</a>'+
                    '<br/>Adresse: ' + markers[i].adresse +
                        '<br/>Ort: ' + markers[i].ort +
                            '<br/>Telefon: ' + markers[i].telefonnum +
                                '<br/>E-Mail: ' + markers[i].email +
                                    '<br/>Kategorie: ' + markers[i].kategorie + 
                                        '<br/>Art: ' + markers[i].art +
                                            '<br/>Bemerkung: ' + markers[i].bemerkung)
     .addTo(markerLayer);
}

controlLayers.addOverlay(markerLayer);
```